# How to read/write googlesheet from android app programmatically?

Tags: android, google-sheets-api

I am trying to develop an app that will read mobile numbers from Googlesheet & send messages to the mobile number & mark the entry in Googlesheet.
I have done all console work(Create project, create key, enable google sheet api etc)

```
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "ReadWriteGoogleSheetContact";
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

/**
 * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
 * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
 */
private static final List<String> SCOPES =
        Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

public void readListFromGSheet() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    final String spreadsheetId = "13NF1-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-PaycpPb0AoAQ";
    final String range = "web_register_tab!A2:F";
    Credential credential = getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT);

    Sheets service =
            new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();
    ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
            .get(spreadsheetId, range)
            .execute();
    List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
    if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No data found.");
    } else {
        for (List row : values) {
            // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
            int id = Integer.parseInt(row.get(0).toString());
            String name = row.get(1).toString();
            String phone = row.get(2).toString();
            String email = row.get(3).toString();
            String date = row.get(4).toString();
            String register_time = row.get(5).toString();

            WebinarRegister webinarRegister = new WebinarRegister(id, name, phone, email, date, register_time);

            String message = tvMessage.getText().toString();
            tvMessage.setText(message + "\n" + webinarRegister.getName());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Creates an authorized Credential object.
 *
 * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
 * @return An authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
 */
private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT)
        throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = MainActivity.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    if (in == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    }
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    File f = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File tokenFolder = new File(f + File.separator + TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH);
    if (!tokenFolder.exists()) {
        boolean is_done = tokenFolder.mkdirs();

        String message = "Token Folder Not created";
        if (is_done) {
            message = "Token Folder created";
        }
        Log.i(TAG, message);
    }

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(tokenFolder))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();

    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    Credential cred = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    return cred;
}
```

It is failing at

```
 LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
Credential cred = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
return cred;
```

Error in Short

```
Process: com.example.sms_application, PID: 20972java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer;
at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(LocalServerReceiver.java:127)
at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:109)
at com.example.sms_application.ui.login.MainActivity.getCredentials(MainActivity.java:183)
at com.example.sms_application.ui.login.MainActivity.readListFromGSheet(MainActivity.java:97)
```

Error in Long

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sms_application, PID: 20972
               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer;
                                                                                                    at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(LocalServerReceiver.java:127)
                                                                                                    at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:109)
                                                                                                    at com.example.sms_application.ui.login.MainActivity.getCredentials(MainActivity.java:183)
                                                                                                    at com.example.sms_application.ui.login.MainActivity.readListFromGSheet(MainActivity.java:97)
                                                                                                    at com.example.sms_application.ui.login.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:79)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7762)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7735)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:860)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29326)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8299)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
                                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.sms_application/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes4.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~yjJT0k7pTSCXrlOwxp_JIA==/com.example.sms_application-JnKyCa6SJPv5Frxkm1537A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~yjJT0k7pTSCXrlOwxp_JIA==/com.example.sms_application-JnKyCa6SJPv5Frxkm1537A==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                                    at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(LocalServerReceiver.java:127) 
                                                                                                    at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:109) 
                                                                                                    at com.example.sms_application.ui.login.MainActivity.getCredentials(MainActivity.java:183) 
                                                                                                    at com.example.sms_application.ui.login.MainActivity.readListFromGSheet(MainActivity.java:97) 
                                                                                                    at com.example.sms_application.ui.login.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:79) 
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7762) 
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131) 
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7735) 
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:860) 
                                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29326) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8299) 
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576) 
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
```